# i am trying to get the script tags with src using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have this code which is giving me the data

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").timeout(10000).get();
Elements scripts = doc.select("script");

for (Element script : scripts) {
    String type = script.attr("type");
    if (type.contentEquals("text/javascript")) {
        String scriptData = script.data(); // your text from the script
        break;
    }
}
```

but i want to get the all the <script src of my page, i don't need the text inside it.

what i am missing here

Comment: The part where you call the function for getting the `src` attribute instead of the `.data()`? Look up the Jsoup API docs, find the docs that explain the API for DOM nodes, and then call the appropriate method for getting what you need out of them.

Comment: Instead of `String scriptData = script.data();`  use `String scriptData = script.outerHtml();` or `String scriptData = script.toString();`